# Android - exclude library(jar) class from ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my project but I get these exceptions :

```
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
Class       = [com/sun/mail/pop3/Protocol]
Method      = [quit()Z]
Instruction = [24] aload_3 v3
Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class       = [com/sun/mail/pop3/Protocol]
Method      = [quit()Z]
Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
```

I've tried this : `-keep class com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol{ *; }`
but it does not help. How to exclude this class from ProGuard processing at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if updating your Android SDK and notably android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar to the latest version (ProGuard 4.10 at this time) solves the problem. The ProGuard jars are backward compatible, so you can simply download the latest version from the [ProGuard site](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) and copy the jar.

Otherwise, you can report a bug on ProGuard's bug tracker. You can probably work around the problem by switching off optimization with `-dontoptimize` in your ProGuard configuration file.